# Can not deserialize instance of int out of VALUE_FALSE token while readng docker info client.infoCmd().exec();(docker java api version 0.10.4)

Tags: java, api, docker, version

Getting below error while reading info by client.infoCmd().exec(); with com.github.docker-java,docker-java,version 0.10.4. 
Basically I want to check the docker info in my java program for that I am using docker java api version 0.10.4 and my docker version is 1.9.0 . Please help the way by which I can get docker info
Link to read more about https://github.com/docker-java/docker-java ()

```
Apr 10, 2017 11:22:59 PM org.glassfish.jersey.filter.LoggingFilter log
INFO: 2 * Client response received on thread main
2 < 200
2 < Content-Length: 1149
2 < Content-Type: application/json
2 < Date: Mon, 10 Apr 2017 17:54:20 GMT
2 < Server: Docker/1.9.0 (linux)
{"ID":"U2BQ:6IX2:ZB2G:37GA:43EA:7R3Y:36BG:2TEU:BVJE:VIGK:NMVC:GD6P","Containers":5,"Images":17,"Driver":"aufs","DriverStatus":[["Root Dir","/var/lib/docker/aufs"],["Backing Filesystem","extfs"],["Dirs","27"],["Dirperm1 Supported","false"]],"MemoryLimit":true,"SwapLimit":false,"CpuCfsPeriod":true,"CpuCfsQuota":true,"IPv4Forwarding":true,"BridgeNfIptables":true,"BridgeNfIp6tables":true,"Debug":false,"NFd":15,"OomKillDisable":true,"NGoroutines":22,"SystemTime":"2017-04-10T23:24:20.757276747+05:30","ExecutionDriver":"native-0.2","LoggingDriver":"json-file","NEventsListener":0,"KernelVersion":"3.13.0-24-generic","OperatingSystem":"Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS","IndexServerAddress":"https://index.docker.io/v1/","RegistryConfig":{"InsecureRegistryCIDRs":["127.0.0.0/8"],"IndexConfigs":{"docker.io":{"Name":"docker.io","Mirrors":null,"Secure":true,"Official":true}},"Mirrors":null},"InitSha1":"","InitPath":"/usr/bin/docker","NCPU":2,"MemTotal":4108566528,"DockerRootDir":"/var/lib/docker","HttpProxy":"","HttpsProxy":"","NoProxy":"","Name":"Suchrita","Labels":null,"ExperimentalBuild":false,"ServerVersion":"1.9.0","ClusterStore":"","ClusterAdvertise":""}


Exception in thread "main" javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: Error reading entity from input stream.
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.InboundMessageContext.readEntity(InboundMessageContext.java:866)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.InboundMessageContext.readEntity(InboundMessageContext.java:783)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientResponse.readEntity(ClientResponse.java:326)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.translate(JerseyInvocation.java:786)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.access$500(JerseyInvocation.java:91)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$2.call(JerseyInvocation.java:683)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:228)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:424)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.invoke(JerseyInvocation.java:679)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.method(JerseyInvocation.java:408)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.get(JerseyInvocation.java:308)
    at com.github.dockerjava.jaxrs.InfoCmdExec.execute(InfoCmdExec.java:26)
    at com.github.dockerjava.jaxrs.InfoCmdExec.execute(InfoCmdExec.java:12)
    at com.github.dockerjava.jaxrs.AbstrDockerCmdExec.exec(AbstrDockerCmdExec.java:47)
    at com.github.dockerjava.core.command.AbstrDockerCmd.exec(AbstrDockerCmd.java:26)
    at com.spring.controller.DockerTest.docinfo(DockerTest.java:31)
    at com.spring.controller.DockerTest.main(DockerTest.java:39)
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of int out of VALUE_FALSE token
 at [Source: org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor$UnCloseableInputStream@44be0077; line: 1, column: 259] (through reference chain: com.github.dockerjava.api.model.Info["SwapLimit"])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.from(JsonMappingException.java:164)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.mappingException(DeserializationContext.java:599)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdDeserializer._parseInteger(StdDeserializer.java:331)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.NumberDeserializers$IntegerDeserializer.deserialize(NumberDeserializers.java:202)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.NumberDeserializers$IntegerDeserializer.deserialize(NumberDeserializers.java:187)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.SettableBeanProperty.deserialize(SettableBeanProperty.java:375)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.FieldProperty.deserializeAndSet(FieldProperty.java:107)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:308)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:121)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader._bind(ObjectReader.java:1169)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader.readValue(ObjectReader.java:625)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json.JacksonJsonProvider.readFrom(JacksonJsonProvider.java:448)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor$TerminalReaderInterceptor.invokeReadFrom(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:264)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor$TerminalReaderInterceptor.aroundReadFrom(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:234)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor.proceed(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:154)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyFactory.readFrom(MessageBodyFactory.java:1124)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.InboundMessageContext.readEntity(InboundMessageContext.java:851)
    ... 18 more
```